# How to calculate the f score for seq2seq model for grammar correction?

Tags: python, deep-learning, evaluation, seq2seq, encoder-decoder

I am building a seq2seq model for grammar correction, and I want to calculate F score for my model. But I don’t know how ? Can you help me please

In the evaluation loop I am only calculating the loss, what do I need the model to output so I can use it in calculating f score? And how?

Comment: use the formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score  `Fscore=2*precision*recall/(precision+recall)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.